# How to get workspace of jenkins pipeline plugin job (WorkflowRun object java API )

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-workflow

In the java API,   I can access to  the workspace path from the Run.java object:
(Until today, all objects were instance of hudson.model.AbstractBuild)

1. hudson.model.AbstractBuild#getWorkspace()
2. hudson.model.Run#getExecutor().getCurrentWorkspace()

In Pipeline plugin I don’t have an access to the workspace, the run object is instance of org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun and this object doesn’t link to any workspace.

this call return null: hudson.model.Run#getExecutor().getCurrentWorkspace()

how can I get it?

thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Took me a while to figure it out. 
You can access the workspaces (as a workflow run can have multiple workspaces) from the WorkflowRun in the following way:

```
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.flow.FlowExecution;
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.graph.FlowGraphWalker;
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.graph.FlowNode;
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.graph.StepStartNode;
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.nodes.StepStartNode;
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.actions.WorkspaceAction
...
...
b = item.getLastBuild()

if (b instanceof WorkflowRun) {
  exec = b.getExecution();
  if(exec == null)
    continue;
  FlowGraphWalker w = new FlowGraphWalker(exec);
  for (FlowNode n : w) {
    if (n instanceof StepStartNode) {
      action = n.getAction(WorkspaceAction);
      if (action) {
        String node = action.getNode().toString();
        String workspace = action.getPath().toString();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You now have the node and the workspace on it. This will capture workspaces acquired by the node step as well as workspaces acquired by the ws step.
You probably want to store the node/workspaces, as you will most probalby get several of them on a complex pipeline.

Comment: What is `item` in your first code line `b = item.getLastBuild()` I am building a pipeline steps plugin and inside my plugin need to determine the current workspace directory, from where my plugin's call was initiated.

Comment: This worked well (I had to change `continue` to `return` since this isn't in a loop).  Depending on context, you may need to get **b** using `Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName('myjob').getLastBuild()` or `.getBuildByNumber(n)`

Comment: Thanks for this, I made [the code](https://github.com/akomakom/jenkins-scripts/blob/master/post-build-scripts.groovy) more groovy-like and adapted it to work in the context of the [global-post-script](https://plugins.jenkins.io/global-post-script/) plugin.  It handles both normal and pipeline jobs.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this:

```
node {
  withEnv(["WORKSPACE=${pwd()}"]) {
    echo WORKSPACE
  }
}
```

See [this](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33511) reference for more info.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm not sure how it can help me..
I need an access from my plugin (java plugin). 
I'm working with the back-end objects: WorkflowRun.java and FlowNode.java.
and need an access point from those classes

Comment: My bad. I thought you were referring to accessing via pipeline code.