# For jenkins pipeline job, how to get workspace URL which contains node number - JENKINS Plugin development

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I am writing a Jenkins plugin, where at end of job I need a URL of workspace.

URL in UI looks like `https://jenkins/job/NAME/BUILD/execution/node/3/ws/`

How do I get "execution/node/3" ? ---> "3"

Free flow jobs works with plugin because the workspace is `https://jenkins/job/NAME/BUILD/ws/`

Can we get node number in perform method? or from any env variable?

```
public void perform(Run run, FilePath workspace, Launcher launcher, TaskListener listener) {

}
```

Have found [similar article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41922630/how-to-get-workspace-of-jenkins-pipeline-plugin-job-workflowrun-object-java-api/57084428#57084428), but not sure what is "item" object.

Comment: This does not look like execution node id. I think it is the pipeline execution step id. 

If you have this plugin [pipeline-stage-view-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-stage-view-plugin/blob/master/rest-api/README.md), you can try opening: `https://<Your Jenkins hostLport>/job/<job-name>/<build number>/execution/node/3/wfapi/`.

You should see "Allocate node : Start" as the step name.